# Are concrete screws suitable for repeated removal and reinstallation?

Tags: concrete, fasteners

Is a concrete screw like the [HILTI HUS3](https://www.hilti.co.uk/c/CLS_FASTENER_7135/CLS_SCREW_ANCHORS_7135/r2523586?CHA_GLOBAL_ANC_SIZE=10%20mm&CHD_ANCHOR_LENGTH=150%20mm&combo_content=fdbaf0c8059ef27f1cb0778dcd54b011&salespackquantity=50%20pc&itemCode=2079918) removable?

I.e. can it be repeatedly unscrewed and reinstalled as required? Will this damage the fixing or the hole in the concrete?

We're thinking about using it for a bund that occasionally will need to be removed for access.

Comment: Use screw/bolt with embed socket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are usually fitted once and left.

If you need to remove them then you need to drill new holes.

Or you should consider fitting a wooden framework to the concrete and attaching to that so it can be easily removed and refitted, without disturbing the concrete fixings.